# Node JS Karma Testing - HotTowel Template extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am teaching myself node.js and I have taken Hot Towel template and begun to extend its function.
I have added a new Controller which implements angular-file-upload.
It works fine up to the point where i try and implement a Karma test against the new module whereupon it throws this error

```
   Chrome 46.0.2490 (Mac OS X 10.11.1) UploadController "before each" hook for "should be created successfully" FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: routerHelperProvider <- routerHelper
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=routerHelperProvider%20%3C-%20routerHelper
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289:19
        at Object.getService [as get] (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:45
        at getService (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
        at Object.invoke (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:79
        at forEach (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:20)
        at Object.createInjector [as injector] (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:3)
        at Context.workFn (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2427:52)
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Mac OS X 10.11.1) UploadController "after each" hook: workFn for "should be created successfully" FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: routerHelperProvider <- routerHelper
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=routerHelperProvider%20%3C-%20routerHelper
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289:19
        at Object.getService [as get] (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:45
        at getService (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
        at Object.invoke (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:79
        at forEach (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:20)
        at Object.createInjector [as injector] (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:3)
        at Context.workFn (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2427:52)
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Mac OS X 10.11.1) upload routes state "before each" hook for "should map state upload to url /upload " FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: routerHelperProvider <- routerHelper
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=routerHelperProvider%20%3C-%20routerHelper
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289:19
        at Object.getService [as get] (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:45
        at getService (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
        at Object.invoke (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
        at /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:79
        at forEach (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:20)
        at Object.createInjector [as injector] (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:3)
        at Context.workFn (/Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2427:52)
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Mac OS X 10.11.1): Executed 42 of 45 (3 FAILED) (0.371 secs / 0.053 secs)
```

The Upload Controller looks like:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.upload',['angularFileUpload'])
        .controller('UploadController', UploadController);

    UploadController.$inject = ['logger','FileUploader','$scope'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function UploadController(logger, FileUploader, scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Upload';

        var uploader = scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: '/upload'
        });

        activate();

        function activate() {
            logger.info('Activated Upload View');
        }

        // FILTERS

        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'customFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                return this.queue.length < 10;
            }
        });

        // CALLBACKS

        uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
            console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
        };
        uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
            console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
        };
        uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
            console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
        };
        uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
            console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
        };
        uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
            console.info('onCompleteAll');
        };

        console.info('uploader', uploader);

    }
})();
```

The upload-routes.js looks like this:-

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.upload')
        .run(appRun);

    appRun.$inject = ['routerHelper'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function appRun(routerHelper) {
        routerHelper.configureStates(getStates());
    }

    function getStates() {
        return [
            {
                state: 'upload',
                config: {
                    url: '/upload',
                    templateUrl: 'app/upload/upload.html',
                    controller: 'UploadController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    title: 'Upload',
                    settings: {
                        nav: 3,
                        content: '<i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Upload'
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
    }
})();
```

The test spec looks like:-

```
/* jshint -W117, -W030 */
describe('UploadController', function() {
    var controller;

    beforeEach(function() {
        bard.appModule('app.upload');
        bard.inject('$controller', '$log', '$rootScope');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        controller = $controller('UploadController');
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    bard.verifyNoOutstandingHttpRequests();

    describe('Upload controller', function() {

        it('should be created successfully', function () {

            expect(controller).to.be.defined;
        });

        describe('after activate', function() {
            it('should have title of Upload', function() {
                expect(controller.title).to.equal('Upload');
            });

            it('should have logged "Activated"', function() {
                expect($log.info.logs).to.match(/Activated/);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I found a link that indicated that this error occurs when all required dependencies are not loaded.
The build is orchestrated by gulp.
The gulp.js and gulp.config files look ok and the right resources are loaded in the browser.

When i run gulp in SingleRun mode = False and spawn an instance of Chrome i get the following in the console.log:-

```
15 11 2015 23:21:37.527:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)
15 11 2015 23:21:37.528:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map /
15 11 2015 23:21:37.528:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map
15 11 2015 23:21:37.529:DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map to localhost:8888
15 11 2015 23:21:37.531:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)
15 11 2015 23:21:37.532:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map /
15 11 2015 23:21:37.532:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map
15 11 2015 23:21:37.532:DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map to localhost:8888
15 11 2015 23:21:37.533:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)
15 11 2015 23:21:37.534:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map /
15 11 2015 23:21:37.534:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map
15 11 2015 23:21:37.534:DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map to localhost:8888
15 11 2015 23:21:37.535:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)
15 11 2015 23:21:37.536:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map /
15 11 2015 23:21:37.546:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map
15 11 2015 23:21:37.546:DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map to localhost:8888
15 11 2015 23:21:37.547:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)
15 11 2015 23:21:37.548:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map /
15 11 2015 23:21:37.548:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map
15 11 2015 23:21:37.548:DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map to localhost:8888
15 11 2015 23:21:37.549:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)
15 11 2015 23:21:37.549:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map /
15 11 2015 23:21:37.549:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/simon/Documents/Development/angular_dev/billrecon/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map
15 11 2015 23:21:37.550:DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map to localhost:8888
15 11 2015 23:21:37.550:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /base/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)
```

***EDIT - ran gulp test --startServers=true - to ensure the server was started and it overcame the connected refused error. Still get the routerHelperProvider issue though

The files exist in the right place.

I think I am doing something obvious wrong but I cant see it.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the version of phantomjs. So you need to do a couple of things.

1. Download the latest version of phantomjs from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)
2. At the command prompt uninstall the following libraries: 
   npm uninstall phantomjs karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
3. At the command prompt install the following libraries: 
   npm install --save-dev phantomjs-prebuilt phantomjs2 karma-phantomjs2-launcher
4. Update any references in the code from phantomjs to phantomjs2